# How to set zero value of reflectance number of land using QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I try to get SST (Sea Surface Temperature) data from Landsat image using QGIS, but I don't know how to set zero value of reflectance in land area using QGIS.

Does anyone know of any method to set the zero value in land area?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a polygon shapefile covering the land area with a projection similar to the Landsat image, then you need to do the following:

1. Create a polygon covering the extent of the Landsat image from which you will calculate the SST. You can create the extent polygon from `Vector -> Research Tools -> Polygon from Extent Layer`. Make sure the extent of the polygon is same as the extent of the Landsat image.
2. Use difference tool from `Vector -> Geoprocessing Tools -> Difference`, and use the extent polygon created in step 1 as input and land polygon shapefile as difference polygon, and you will get an output that covers only the sea area.
3. Use Merge Tool to merge again the output from step 2 (sea area polygon) and land polygon. The Merge is located in `Vector -> Data Management Tool -> Merge Shapefiles to one` **OR** you can download MMQGIS from plugin manager and use the tool `MMQGIS -> Combine -> Merge layers`. The output should be a polygon shapefile composed of land area and sea sea.
4. Start editing of the output polygon (land area and sea sea ) from step 3, and add a new field name MASK for example and choose a type of integer.
5. Give a value of '0' to land area and a value of '1' to sea area, and save edits then stop editing.
6. Convert polygon to raster from `Raster -> Conversion -> Rasterize (Vector to Raster)`, and choose the polygon of step 4 and the attribute field 'MASK' created in step 5. Make sure you select 'Raster Size in Pixel' and enter a value that match the Landsat pixel size, which is 30m, I think.
7. You will have a raster image that its pixels are 0 for land area and 1 for sea area.
8. Open `Raster -> Raster Calculator` and multiply the output raster from step 6 with Landsat (SST) image. The output image will be an image that represents SST value as it is in the sea area, whereas the land will be masked to 0.